# Problem with SerialIO package and Lego NXT

Tags: interoperability, mac-os-x

I'm following a [guide](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2013/03/controlling-robots-built-with-the-lego-mindstorms-nxt-brick/#Raguet-Schofield) from The Mathematica Journal that describes how to use Mathematica with the Lego Mindstorms NXT but have some trouble getting started and got stuck with the [SerialIO](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5726/) package.

I use Mac OSX and I have installed the package to:

```
/Applications/Mathematica.app/AddOns/ExtraPackages/SerialIO/
```

The command `` Needs["SerialIO`"] `` gives me the following error message:

```
LinkOpen::linke: Could not find MathLink executable.
```

And trying

```
SetDirectory[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "ExtraPackages", "SerialIO", $SystemID}]];
```

Does not help either, it gives:

```
SetDirectory::cdir: Cannot set current directory to /Applications/Mathematica.app/AddOns/ExtraPackages/SerialIO/MacOSX-x86-64.
```

There seem to be some problem with the alias/symbolic link in the SerialIO folder. By default they pointed to an absolute directory on the machine that this library was built on:

```
MacOSX-x86-64 -> /Files/schofield/Packages/SerialIO/Build/Mac/build/Deployment/Package/SerialIO/MacOSX
```

I tried deleting the alias and creating a symbolic link in the terminal:

```
# ln -s MacOSX MacOSX-x86-64
```

Running the `SetDirectory` command again result in... no result, so I guess thats good. The commands seem to have been loaded as when typing *Serial* it want to autocomplete to `SerialOpen` etc.

However, using the command `mybrick = SerialOpen["NXT"]` does not put the NXT in connected mode (<> on NXT display). Does anyone else got it to work?

Comment: I think I had the same problem on windows. The solution was to move the file SerialIO.exe in the same directory as init.m

Comment: @andre I tried this but unfortunately it did no difference. I got it to work however, see my answer :)

Comment: try changing `Install["SerialIO"]` to have the full path to the SerialIO executable.  Also try runing the executable alone in a terminal and make sure it gives you the "create link" prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work with a little help of [this](http://williamjturkel.net/2011/12/25/connecting-arduino-to-mathematica-on-mac-os-x-with-serialio/) and a [git hub repo](https://github.com/ragfield/SerialIO) of the SerialIO package.

The problem was the line `$Link = Install["SerialIO"]` in `init.m`. This seem to only be valid on Windows so I changed this to the suggested `$Link = Install["SerialIO", LinkProtocol->"Pipes"]` and it now works.

Also, the `mybrick = SerialOpen["/dev/tty.NXT"]` had to include the full path to the serial port.

OSX aliases did not work either. I had to create a symbolic link alternatively create a "MacOSX-x86-64" folder with the SerialIO application to make it work.

Comment: This is very unusual.  `Install["executablename"]` is valid on all platforms.  The preferred link type is the default shared memory one, not pipes.  I'm not sure why only pipes worked with this package.

Comment: It might have to do with that it reads the serial port as a file (/dev/tty.Portname). Just guessing :) Forgot to add that I had to change this too so I have updated the answer.

Comment: It is unrelated to that.  There should be no difference regardless of what the program that you `Install` actually does.  That option specifies how Mathematica will communicate with the external program (the underlying protocol of MathLink).  Try the suggestion from my other comment: include the full path of the external program and also see what it does if you run it standalone.

Comment: @Szabolcs Just tested this and using `$Link = Install["/Applications/Mathematica.app/AddOns/ExtraPackages/SerialIO/MacOSX/SerialIO"]` just seem to hang evaluation but running SerialIO standalone displays the "Create Link: " prompt.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.  The precompiled version available for download is quite out of date. The reason LinkProtocol->"Pipes" is necessary with the older version is due to an incompatibility between the v6 MathLink and v7,8,9.

Comment: @ragfield I see :) I guess the version on github is more up to date? I tried building it but got a lot of errors so I guess I'm not doing it right. Could you make a short guide how to build? or even better make a new package?

Comment: @ihatetoregister The source code is the same.  The problem was the version of MathLink the compiled binary was linked against.  I intend to clean it up at some point, but I need to find a chunk of time to do so.