# How do I resolve the "Specified file is not a MathLink executable" in SerialIO package?

Tags: interoperability, ubuntu

I've read and tried the previous StackExchange suggestions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23826/problem-with-serialio-package-and-lego-nxt) about installing the SerialIO package (including placing SerialIO in the same folder as init.m and  and editing the init.m file per [Turkel](http://williamjturkel.net/2011/12/25/connecting-arduino-to-mathematica-on-mac-os-x-with-serialio/). But when I use

```
 <<SerialIO`
```

I still get the error

```
LinkOpen::linke: Specified file is not a MathLink executable..
```

(I installed SerialIO from the github repository on a Ubtuntu 12.04 64 bit machine).

(Using **Terminal**) when I change directory to the SerialIO folder and run the script

```
./SerialIO
```

I see the "Create Link" and "Connect to Link" prompts.

I have 2 related questions:

1. What should be entered at the Create Link / Connect to Link prompts to ensure SerialIO can 'connect' to a device on my system?
2. What else can I check/adjust to have *Mathematica* correctly call the SerialIO package ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it working (M8 on Ubuntu 12.04)! **The answer here is not elegant, may use redundant commands and may not work across other systems.**  But it got M8 in contact with the USB port and my Arduino.  I used the SerialIO package on [Wolfram site](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5726)).

Some suggestions/commands that may be useful in troubleshooting:

### Identifying the USB connection for the device

In **Terminal**, you can use the command below (\$ is my shorthand for the terminal prompt.  Don't type the $, but you do need a space between ls *and* /dev/..)

```
 $   ls /dev/tty*
```

and try plugging your device in/out and rerunning the ***ls*** command. You'll soon figure out what is changing. On my system the Arduino Uno appears under /dev/ttyACM <+values>.   Other Linux systems may show up as /dev/ttyUSB <+values>.  So I generally start (in Terminal) with

```
 $   ls /dev/ttyACM*
```

to find the device.  On my machine, the values may *increment* each time its plugged in e.g. a device unplugged from `/dev/ttyACM0` may reconnect at  `/dev/ttyACM1`.

you can also do this in **Mathematica** using the function below which also returns values you can use in other commands:

```
usblist = ReadList["!ls /dev/ttyACM*", String]
```

As outlined above, adjust the command to fit your system (eg `.../ttyACM*` or `.../ttyUSB*` etc).  The * part returns all names that begin with the prefix ..ACM".   Look up the definition of `ReadList` and the "`!`" to understand how this interesting command allows Mathematica to get information directly from your OS.

### Using SerialIO in a Notebook

Before calling the SerialIO package in the notebook, I changed directory to the one where I unzipped the `SerialIO` package. Since I put mine in `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/AddOns/Packages/`, I used the command

```
SetDirectory[$InstallationDirectory <> "/AddOns/Packages/SerialIO/" <> $SystemID]
```

Assuming your folder structure is standard and you installed `SerialIO` under the M8 directory structure then the `$InstallationDirectory` takes care of the main part of the path (up to the ../8.0 in my case), "/AddOns/Packages/SerialIO" is the "glue" to the specific SerialIO folder under Mathematica and `$SystemID` is your OS specific file path (from MacOSX, Windows, Windows-x-64 etc) within the SerialIO folder itself.  (To test these values you can evaluate the commands `$InstallationDirectory` and `$SystemID` in a notebook)

**To start a SerialIO Link use**

```
Install["./SerialIO"]
```

to load the SerialIO package.   I tried `Needs` and `<<` with their formatting (quotes and backticks) but they either didn't work and/or didn't return error messages.  If this works, the Output should return info on a `LinkObject` such as:

```
LinkObject["/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/AddOns/Packages/SerialIO/Linux-x86-64/SerialIO", 137309, 10]
```

**If you don't see a LinkObject, you need to do more digging**.    A handy function is `reportPackages` from [wilbert van meerwijk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/listing-the-functions-defined-in-a-package) that you can include in your notebook here and double-check SerialIO Package is installed.

Another command to show you have established a connection to SerialIO is `Links[]` . Again, the output should include a LinkObject like the example above.

To connect to a device (eg an Arduino), set comms parameters and get data, you need to know the path the Arduino is on and elect the same baud rate that your Arduino sketch is sending data, as defined in `Serial.begin` function e.g  `Serial.begin(115200)`;

Mathematica commands (myArduino is a arbitrary description):

```
myArduino = SerialOpen["/dev/ttyACM2"]
SerialSetOptions[myArduino, "BaudRate" -> 115200]
x = Dynamic[Table[SerialRead[myArduino], {10}], UpdateInterval ->1]
```

If the Arduino is streaming values to the Serial port with line terminations (e.g `Serial.println(value)` , then the `Dynamic` function picks them up in groups of 10 and updates their display in M8 once a second.  For this to work, under the Mathematica menu choice `Evaluation`, check the box for `Dynamic Updating Enabled`.

### Unfinished business - direct USB baud control

I have found that the `SerialSetOptions` does not always set the baud rate and you see gibberish characters coming through. I instead use **`Terminal`** before calling the M8 `SerialOpen` command.  So in **Terminal**

```
$  stty 115200 cs8 -parenb crtscts -echo -F /dev/ttyACM2
```

builds on what we already know to set the baud rate on the PC side.  Change baud rate (here `115200`) and the path to the device (here `/dev/ttyACM2`) based on the baud rate of your Arduino's output and device path.

I'll update/edit if I can solve any of these issues.

## EDIT: REVISION/IMPROVEMENT

The code below uses Mathematica alone to identify, and set the baud rate for, the device connection. It assumes the *highest numbered device* is the Arduino.

**Load the SerialIO Package:**
I don't know why, but for dependable function it seems to need both  `Install` and `Needs`, at least for an initial run.

```
SetDirectory[$InstallationDirectory <> "/AddOns/Packages/SerialIO/" <> $SystemID]    
Install["./SerialIO"]  
Needs["SerialIO`"]
```

and you should see a LinkObject created e.g.

```
LinkObject["/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/AddOns/Packages/SerialIO/Linux-x86-64/SerialIO", 732, 22]
```

Now find the device (assuming its the highest number).  Reflecting the techniques on [this page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10619/sort-strings-by-natural), *Natural number sorting* is required to identify device in case we get into double digits i.e so that `/dev/ttyACM10` follows `/dev/ttyACM9` and is `Last`.

(Edit the `/dev/.` path as described to search on your machine. An other choice might be `"!ls /dev/ttyUSB*"`).

```
wherePorts = ReadList["!ls /dev/ttyACM*", String];
whereArduino = Last@wherePorts[[Ordering[Characters[wherePorts]]]]
```

Prepare the Arduino's port (using 57600 baud in this example) by running  the `stty` `[+options]` command. The `SerialSetOptions` function of SerialIO didn't work in my hands to set baud rate. 
Then open Serial through the SerialIO command `SerialOpen`.

```
setArduino="stty 57600 cs8 -parenb crtscts -echo -F " <> whereArduino
Run[setArduino];
Pause[2]     
myArduino = SerialOpen[whereArduino]
```

Gather some data (here, 10 "sets").

```
fromArduino=Table[SerialRead[myArduino],{10}]
```

## EDIT#2

Apologies for the length but an improved way to find the path to your Arduino assuming its the *last device plugged in* is to probe the system log via `dmesg`.  In my case, the Arduino is the last log entry that includes the phrase being searched i.e "USB ACM device".  The approach is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183880/how-to-find-out-which-usb-rs232-device-is-on-which-tty) and might need adjustment as to the phrase being grepp'd.  Typing `dmesg` into your **Teriminal** will list all system events in chronological order (last at bottom of list) and you can choose from there.
This Mathematica code does the `dmesg` and `grep`, cuts the String into pieces at ":", takes the 2nd last entry and `Joins` it to give a path string that can now be used:

```
betterwhere =  StringTrim@StringSplit[Last@ReadList["!dmesg | grep 'USB ACM device'", String], ":"];  
betterwhere2 = betterwhere[[-2]];
whereArduino2 = "/dev/" <> betterwhere2;
```

Again, your actual path specifics may vary.